# Can two button share same 'click' function?

Tags: javascript, php

I have two buttons.One is named Update and another one is view. Both buttons are working perfectly. But if I duplicated 2 buttons, only view button is working. Update button is just displayed and not doing any click function.

WORKING Code:

```
<button id="AttendanceEnter" name="attendance" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
<button id="Attendanceview" name="attendanceview" class="btn btn-success">View</button>
```

Not Working Code:

```
<button id="AttendanceEnter" name="attendance" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>

//ABove Code function is working,click function WORKING
//Below button only displaying, click function NOT working

<button id="AttendanceEnter1" name="attendance" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>

//Below 2 buttons are working perfectly,Clicks are working 

<button id="Attendanceview" name="attendanceview" class="btn btn-success">View</button>
<button id="Attendanceview" name="attendanceview" class="btn btn-success">View</button>
```

Complete js is here:
*Contains click function only for Update buttons*

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $('.select_date').datepicker({
        autoclose: true,
        dateFormat: date_format,
        todayHighlight: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        maxDate: 0
    });

    /*Retrive Student List */
    $('#AttendanceEnter').click(function() {

        $( '#AttendanceClass' ).parent().parent().find('label').removeClass( 'error' );
        $( '#AttendanceDate' ).parent().parent().find('label').removeClass( 'error' );

        $('#AddModalContent').html('');
        $( '#wpsp-error-msg' ).html('');        
        var cid     =   $('#AttendanceClass').val();
        var date    =   $('#AttendanceDate').val();
        if( cid=='' )
            $( '#AttendanceClass' ).parent().parent().find('label').addClass( 'error' );
        if( date=='' )
            $( '#AttendanceDate' ).parent().parent().find('label').addClass( 'error' );
        if(cid!='' && date!=''){
            var data=[];
            data.push({name: 'action', value: 'getStudentsList'},{name: 'classid', value: cid},{name:'date',value:date});
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: ajax_url,
                data: data,
                beforeSend:function () {
                    $.fn.notify('loader',{'desc':'Loading student list..'});
                    $('#AttendanceEnter').attr("disabled", 'disabled');
                },
                success: function( response ) {
                    $('#AttendanceEnter').removeAttr('disabled');
                    var response_data = jQuery.parseJSON(response);             
                    if( response_data.status == 0 ) {
                        $( '#wpsp-error-msg' ).html(response_data.msg);
                        $( '#AddModal' ).modal( 'hide' );
                    } else {                                
                        $('#AddModalContent').html(response_data.msg);
                    }
                },
                error:function(){
                    $('#AttendanceEnter').removeAttr('disabled');
                    $.fn.notify('error',{'desc':'Something went wrong. Try after refreshing page..'});
                },
                complete:function () {
                    $('#AttendanceEnter').removeAttr('disabled');
                    $('.pnloader').remove();
                }
            });
            $('#AddModal').modal('show');
        }
    });
///
/*Retrive Student List */
$('#AttendanceEnter1').click(function() {

    $( '#AttendanceClass' ).parent().parent().find('label').removeClass( 'error' );
    $( '#AttendanceDate' ).parent().parent().find('label').removeClass( 'error' );

    $('#AddModalContent').html('');
    $( '#wpsp-error-msg' ).html('');        
    var cid     =   $('#AttendanceClass').val();
    var date    =   $('#AttendanceDate').val();
    if( cid=='' )
        $( '#AttendanceClass' ).parent().parent().find('label').addClass( 'error' );
    if( date=='' )
        $( '#AttendanceDate' ).parent().parent().find('label').addClass( 'error' );
    if(cid!='' && date!=''){
        var data=[];
        data.push({name: 'action', value: 'getStudentsList'},{name: 'classid', value: cid},{name:'date',value:date});
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: ajax_url,
            data: data,
            beforeSend:function () {
                $.fn.notify('loader',{'desc':'Loading student list..'});
                $('#AttendanceEnter1').attr("disabled", 'disabled');
            },
            success: function( response ) {
                $('#AttendanceEnter1').removeAttr('disabled');
                var response_data = jQuery.parseJSON(response);             
                if( response_data.status == 0 ) {
                    $( '#wpsp-error-msg' ).html(response_data.msg);
                    $( '#AddModal' ).modal( 'hide' );
                } else {                                
                    $('#AddModalContent').html(response_data.msg);
                }
            },
            error:function(){
                $('#AttendanceEnter1').removeAttr('disabled');
                $.fn.notify('error',{'desc':'Something went wrong. Try after refreshing page..'});
            },
            complete:function () {
                $('#AttendanceEnter1').removeAttr('disabled');
                $('.pnloader').remove();
            }
        });
        $('#AddModal').modal('show');
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, they can, but can you trim your code down to a [MCVE]? (329 lines is too much)

Comment: I'll try to  that

Comment: I added click function only for Update buttons. Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `name` attributes should also be unique in this case. Your buttons have duplicated `name` attributes which will confuse `HTTP`.

Comment: You are right. It is working now. But why name should be different ?? 'name' is not used reference.

Comment: HTTP such as the `GET` and `POST` methods use the `name` attributes. `id` is typically consumed by the DOM client through CSS and JS. There are other scenarios. The aforementioned is the default behaviour. Hope this comment helps whoever downvoted my answer so that others too can benefit.

Answer (score 1):

using jquery  you can do something like

```
$("#AttendanceEnter , #Attendanceview").click(function(){
//your code
});
```